# Figure counter is not incrementing after use of paracol

Tags: counters, paracol

I am using one column environment to write text and put figures with their captions. At a certain point I had a longitudinal figure to integrate so I wanted to put its caption laterally by using `paracol`. Everything worked as expected, except that `figure` counter was not updated when I get back to one column environment.

Here is the minimal example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\LARGE{ONECOL}
\caption[onecol]{onecol}
\end{figure}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\begin{leftcolumn}
\centering
\LARGE{PARACOL}
\end{leftcolumn}
\begin{rightcolumn}
\begin{figure}
\caption[paracol]{paracol }
\end{figure}
\end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\LARGE{ONECOL}
\caption[onecol]{onecol}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]
How could I fix that? Or is there another way to have the same output with well behaved figure counter incrementation?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`paracol` explicitly defines all counters (except `page` counter) to be 'local' in columns, i.e. the values inside of `paracol` environment` are not transmitted to the outer document.

If this is not wanted, `\globalcounter{figure}` (for example) is to be used in the preamble of the file.  (See section 5.3 of the current `paracol` manual for more information on this)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlof, notlot]{tocbibind}

\globalcounter{figure}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \LARGE{ONECOL}
  \caption[onecol]{onecol}
\end{figure}

\begin{paracol}{2}
  \begin{leftcolumn}
    \centering
    \LARGE{PARACOL}
  \end{leftcolumn}
  \begin{rightcolumn}
    \begin{figure}
      \caption[paracol]{paracol }
    \end{figure}
  \end{rightcolumn}
\end{paracol}

\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \LARGE{ONECOL}
  \caption[onecol]{onecol}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you man!! I took a look on that manual but did not catch the info.. Anyway I am happy that a solution exist and thanks again for the quick answer

Comment: @Giblar: You're welcome. Happy TeXing! Please consider to register to have extended possibilities here on this site