# Three column mode with figure env

Tags: floats, paracol

I need three column mode and found a stable solution in
[Three column layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/497049/three-column-layout). Thank you for that.
As I need figures I have integrated them. Unfortunately the counting of the figures are awkward as you can see in the out put below. Starred version does not help.
Does anyone knows a solution or what is going wrong?

The mwe

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[left=2cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

    \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}

    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[] {xcolor}

    \usepackage[figurename=Abb]{caption}
    \graphicspath{{../bilder/prunusavium}}

    \usepackage{paracol}
    \setlength{\columnsep}{0.2cm} 
    %%%% Colored lines %%%%
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
    \colseprulecolor{blue}

    \usepackage[]{hyperref}
    %end preamble

    \begin{document}
    \section{Taxonomie}
    \setcolumnwidth{5.7cm,5.95cm,5.95cm}
    \begin{paracol}{3}[\subsection{\textit{Prunus avium}  \textsc{L.} --- Die Vogelkirsche}
               Die  \glqq Pflaume der Vögel\grqq~ kann bis zu 100 Jahre alt und 25 Meter hoch werden. 
              ]
    \switchcolumn[0]
    \begin{figure}[h]       
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth] {../bilder/prunusavium/test.png}
        \caption[Taxonomie]{Taxonomische Stufen\\ \textit{Prunus avium}}
    \end{figure}
    \switchcolumn[1]
    \sloppy
    \begin{figure}[hbp]
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth] {../bilder/prunusavium/test.png}
        \caption[Prunus avium Blüten]{Blüten}
    \end{figure}
    Die Blüten sind weiß, etwa zwei bis drei Zentimeter breit und zwittrig. 

    \begin{figure}[hbp]
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth] {../bilder/prunusavium/test.png}
        \caption[Prunus avium Blatt]{Blatt}
    \end{figure}
    Die Blätter sind grob doppelt gesägt, eiförmig und enden in einer länglichen Spitze. 

    \switchcolumn[2]
    \begin{figure}[hbp]
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth] {../bilder/prunusavium/test.png}
        \caption[Prunus avium Früchte]{Früchte}
    \end{figure}
    Die Steinfrüchte sind kugelig, erbsengroß und sitzen an nickenden Fruchtstielen.

    \begin{figure}[hbp]
        \includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth] {../bilder/prunusavium/test.png}
        \caption[Prunus avium Rinde]{Rinde}
        \label{fig:prunusaviumrinde}
    \end{figure}
    Glatte, bräunliche Rinde mit waagerecht verlaufenden Korkwarzen.
     \end{paracol}
     \listoffigures
    \end{document}
```

The output

[image: Three column mode with figure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Figure counter is not incrementing after use of paracol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304465/figure-counter-is-not-incrementing-after-use-of-paracol) I have found an answer. Just put '
\globalcounter{figure}' in the preamble. Ingenious. It works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need `paracol` for this.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[figurename=Abb]{caption}

\graphicspath{{../bilder/prunusavium}}

%%%% Colored lines %%%%
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
%end preamble

\begin{document}
\section{Taxonomie}

\subsection{\textit{Prunus avium}~L. --- Die Vogelkirsche}

Die \glqq Pflaume der Vögel\grqq~kann bis zu 100 Jahre alt und 25 Meter hoch werden. 

\begin{figure}[h]   
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  p{5.7cm}
  p{5.95cm}
  p{5.95cm}
}
\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\caption[Taxonomie]{Taxonomische Stufen\\ \textit{Prunus avium}}
&
\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{\example-image}

\caption[Prunus avium Blüten]{Blüten}

\bigskip

Die Blüten sind weiß, etwa zwei bis drei Zentimeter breit und zwittrig.
&
\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\caption[Prunus avium Blatt]{Blatt}

\bigskip

Die Blätter sind grob doppelt gesägt, eiförmig und enden in einer länglichen Spitze.
\\
&
\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\caption[Prunus avium Früchte]{Früchte}

\bigskip

Die Steinfrüchte sind kugelig, erbsengroß und sitzen an nickenden Fruchtstielen.
&
\vspace{0pt}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\caption[Prunus avium Rinde]{Rinde}\label{fig:prunusaviumrinde}

\bigskip

Glatte, bräunliche Rinde mit waagerecht verlaufenden Korkwarzen.
\end{tabular*}

\end{figure}

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for your rapid reply. Out of several reasons I prefer the paracol way. I know about the difficulties (e.g. wrapfigure, but also paracol). I wonder about the wrong count and don't see the right way to do it.